# How to call a controller function from view in MVC 4

Tags: function, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I need to execute a function when user click on menu item, to populate some data in database table.

example of function in controller:

```
        public void PopulateDatabase()
        {
            Populate();
        }
```

how can i call this function from View?

EDIT:

I create an ActionResult method that return a View to inform user that database updated succesfuly like this

```
    public ActionResult PopulateDatabase()
    {
        Populate();
        return View("Populate");
    }
```

and i call it from view with

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PopulateDatabase", "ControllerName")" class="populate">Populate Database</a>
```

i tested and working. Is there a better solution to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this with `@Url.Action` in your view

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <a href="@Url.Action("PopulateDatabase","ControllerNameHere")">MenuItem</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```